# Utility to display received TCP data

Tags: windows-10, tcp

I'm writing code that consumes a TCP protocol - no authentication you just connect and wait for data.
I'd like to display & save this data nicely formatted  - e.g. hex - and before I waste time writing code, it struck me there might be standard utilities to do this... I've similar tools for file/memory inspection.
I'm running Windows 10

Comment: Have you can try Wireshark?

Comment: It's a fairly locked down environment, I might be limited to built-in functionality or applications I can copy across (no installation)

Comment: You mean like a hex dump, or what?

Comment: @spiff yeah that sort of thing

Comment: rawcap - https://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap if you just want to capture the data and then view it in something like Wireshark.  TBH, netsh.exe can start a packet trace if needed.